# Exchange 2016 on server 2012r2 port 25 closed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, smtp, exchange-2016

Port 25 won't open anymore since a few days. I don't know what exactly preceded it, maybe server crash or update. /owa and /ecp work and I can also connect with Outlook, but I can't get any mails. I verified it with https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

I tried connecting from the Server via Telnet localhost 25 but the port just isn't open. I tested disabling the firewall so that doesn't seem to be the issue.
Also some Exchange Services, that should start up automatically don't start up, like Exchange Transport Service. I tried starting it manually, but port is still closed. I'm an Exchange beginner so I don't know exactly which services are crucial.

Comment: Did you ever head of the event log? Log files?

Comment: `Also some Exchange Services, that should start up automatically don't start up, like Exchange Transport Service` - That's the problem. Look in the Event Logs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what they have said above, you could check event log and if there is any error messages?

Do you run Windows antivirus programs on Microsoft Exchange servers, you could follow this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/windows-antivirus-software?view=exchserver-2016) to Check AV exclusion state. 
Can you send out mails? Have you ever updated windows?

You could try to restart server and check if this issue continues.

I found a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45619f7d-f112-4630-b1d9-7e94f79d8ff9/exchange-transport-service-wont-start?forum=Exch2016GD) for your reference: